# When does the crate counter reset?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

[image]

In PUBG, every time you buy a crate, a counter increases and the next crate costs you more.

I've seen this going back to crate #1, but can't figure out when that reset happens. Is it weekly, monthly, decided by player unknown (resetting on updates)?

Also, does going for a higher box give you a better reward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crate reset time is Monday 0:00 UTC (thus it is weekly).  A helpful timer can be found [here](https://pubgcratereset.com/).

As for the rarity, the price does not seem to matter.  Reading [this steam post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/578080/discussions/1/135514507318587882/) seems to indicate this.  From personal experience a well, it seems this way.  They also mention the crate timer resetting on Monday as well.

> All the boxes are 100% the same, price does not matter - 700, 1400, 2800, ... 7000. It all drops the same. Price resets every monday.

Note that depending on your time zone, it may be Sunday when the crate cost resets, but it will reset at the same time no matter what for everyone.

Comment: Side question: Is there a roof to the crate cost?

Comment: @Fredy31 it seems you can get up to 6 crates a week, with the last crate costing 7000.  I'm also going to double check to make sure its 0:00 UTC.  Looking at the timer, and comparing it what the current UTC time is, its actually 01:00.  But I'm not sure if its offset or not due to day light savings, or something else.

Comment: Can confirm that it is 00:00 UTC Monday.  I watched my crate cost go from 1,400 down to 700 (after restarting the lobby) once 00:00 UTC occurred (7:00pm EDT for me).  That means that the timer linked in my answer doesn't account for day light savings offset.